# What does "intuitive" mean?

Tags: meaning

Kindly explain what does "intuitive" mean in this case? Convenient?

> **Intuitive** alerts about flight delays and schedules.

Source: http://www.eater.com/2015/11/18/9750940/airport-restaurants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context does not expand on the meaning much, but "intuitive" here probably means "easy to use" or "easy to notice", "obvious". We use this word quite often in the tech field:

> an intuitive system, method, piece of software etc is **easy to use** because the process of operating it is **very obvious**
>
> *The new version has a more intuitive user interface.*

([Macmillan English Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/intuitive))